# Whatsapp not found with Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapp

Can you please help me to understand why `com.whatsapp` package is not searchable when using `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, although it is searchable when using`Intent.ACTION_VIEW`

---

**RESOLVED**.

```
private const val WHATSAPP = "com.whatsapp"
    private const val TEL = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    private var url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$TEL&text=${
        URLEncoder.encode(
            "HI there",
            "UTF-8"
        )
    }"

    fun sendMessage() {
        val context = Utils.context()
        if (Utils.isPackageInstalled(WHATSAPP)) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.setPackage(WHATSAPP)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Utils.context(), "$WHATSAPP is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may be because you have not set the intent type, and added the actual content to send. Have you tried doing `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send."); intent.setType("text/plain");`

Comment: So you post code that works. But you dont post your code that does not work? In the code that works its pretty unclear what the url would be. You let us much to guess.

Comment: Updated code example

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I was using whatsapp Business and the call to the package was:

com.whatsapp.w4b